# Change the byte-length of an int represented as a byte

Tags: python, python-3.x

Right now to achieve this, I'm doing:

```py
int.from_bytes(number, 'little').to_bytes(bit_len, 'little')
```

Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: If you're always increasing the number of bytes, and the value is unsigned, you could pad with null bytes using `.ljust()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `shift left` to increase the length or `shitft right` to decrease:

For example:

```
bin(10)      # Output: 0b1010
bin(10 << 2) # Output: 0b101000
bin(10 >> 1) # Output: 0b101
```